# Correct according to British English language rules

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, british-english

I have a sentence which looks as if it may have some grammar rules problems.

Can someone correct it according to British English rules?

> I am going to hospital to see a friend who has undergone the operation.

Comment: close proofreading.  (dont vote down, click to close)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is grammatically correct. By using the definite article *the operation*, I assume it was a very specific operation which the listener will already know about. Otherwise the indefinite article would normally be used.

And in Britain although we talk about a patient being *in hospital*, visitors usually go to *the hospital*. Saying you are *going to hospital* suggests you are going as a patient.

Comment: so we can write like this `Going to hospital to see a friend who has undergone an operation` please guide.

Comment: I would suggest *I am going to the hospital to see a friend who has undergone an operation*.

Comment: Please explain why you used `an` instead of `the`

Comment: @SohailQureshi If the listener knew all about the operation that the friend was due to have, then it would be correct to talk about *the operation*. But if he/she did not know the friend and anything about an operation, then it would be *an operation*. For understanding when to use the definite and when the indefinite article, you probably need to visit the EL& L site.